# How do I install Ubuntu 12.04 by the Windows 7?

Tags: installation, 12.04, windows-7

before, the Ubuntu 11.10 install by windows 7.

Comment: Seriously, I have no idea what you are asking. Please provide more details in your question. What sort of a system are you trying to install to? (laptop? desktop? how old/new? model or manufacturer?) Is Windows 7 already installed? What sort of install are you attempting? From CD? USB? Or are you using Wubi?

Comment: Welcome on AskUbuntu, Wallace. As John said, your question is not very clear indeed. Have you tried to follow the instructions on http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop?

Comment: I have windows 7, and usually I install ubuntu by it, so I was wondering, how to install ubuntu 12.04 by the windows 7 because it was easy to install ubuntu 11.10 by the windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the WUBI installer , and use it to run Ubuntu side by side to your windows 7.